# How do I use the isActive function throughout my application?

Tags: swift, xcode

I created subscriptions and I created an isActive function to know if the subscription is still valid or not.
How can I use this function everywhere in my application? for example in an IF.

thanks

```
    import UIKit
    import StoreKit
    
    public typealias SuccessBlock = () -> Void
    public typealias FailureBlock = (Error?) -> Void
    public typealias ProductsBlock = ([SKProduct]) -> Void
    
    let IAP_PRODUCTS_DID_LOAD_NOTIFICATION = Notification.Name("IAP_PRODUCTS_DID_LOAD_NOTIFICATION")
    
    class IAPManager : NSObject{
        
        private var sharedSecret = ""
        @objc static let shared = IAPManager()
        @objc private(set) var products = [SKProduct]()
        
        private override init(){}
        private var productIds : Set<String> = []
        
        private var didLoadsProducts : ProductsBlock?
        
        private var successBlock : SuccessBlock?
        private var failureBlock : FailureBlock?
        
        private var refreshSubscriptionSuccessBlock : SuccessBlock?
        private var refreshSubscriptionFailureBlock : FailureBlock?
        
        // MARK:- Main methods
        
        @objc func startWith(arrayOfIds : Set<String>!, sharedSecret : String, callback : @escaping  ProductsBlock){
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            self.didLoadsProducts = callback
            self.sharedSecret = sharedSecret
            self.productIds = arrayOfIds
            loadProducts()
        }
        
        func expirationDateFor(_ identifier : String) -> Date?{
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: identifier) as? Date
        }
        
        func isActive(product : SKProduct) -> Bool {
            if let date = expirationDateFor(product.productIdentifier), Date() < date {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a static variable in AppDelegate class and access it where do u want

Comment: Can you give me an example that would work? because I don't understand. Does this variable allow you to check the subscription status each time the app is launched ? thanks for your help it's very important that it works because it's a project for my university.